# Generating labeled images for each glyph in a bitmap font file

Tags: ocr, computer-vision, bitmap-fonts

Is there an easy way to generate a labeled bitmap image for each glyph contained in a given bitmap font file?

I'm trying to convert a collection of Japanese .bdf fonts into a format usable in MATLAB and C++, where each glyph is used as the OCR classification key for the character it represents.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[FontForge](http://fontforge.sourceforge.net/) has support for [Bitmap
Distribution Format (BDF)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glyph_Bitmap_Distribution_Format) files. You can probably export a BMP files from there. I also found [bdf2png](http://search.cpan.org/~dclee/Font-BDF-Reader-0.01/bin/bdf2png). You can read up on the [BDF specification](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/font/pdfs/5005.BDF_Spec.pdf) and implement your own solution, which doesn't seem too bad as the format is in ASCII.